# NDSolve with boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I am trying to solve Laplace's equation with a boundary condition. The condition is that there is a box with zero potential on its walls, a 1D plate with potential V at the top of a two dimensional wire, and a 1D plate with potential -V at the bottom of the wire (the plates have the same radius of my wire). Here is my code, where L is the length of my wire/box, R is the width of my box, and a is the radius of my wire/plates:

```
L = 50;
R = 20;
a = 2;
V = 10;
potent = NDSolveValue[{D[ϕ[x,z],{x,2}]+D[ϕ[x,z],{z,2}]==0,ϕ[0,z]==0,ϕ[R,z]==0,DirichletCondition[ϕ[x,z]==V,(R/2-a)<=x<=(R/2+ a)&&z==0],DirichletCondition[ϕ[x,z]==-V,(R/2-a)<=x<=(R/2+ a)&&z==L],DirichletCondition[ϕ[x,z]==0,((R/2-a)> x||x>(R/2+ a))&&(z==L||z==0)]},ϕ,{x,0,R},{z,0,L}]
ContourPlot[potent, {x, 0, R}, {z, 0, L}]
```

The output in my contour plot is empty. I assume it has something to do with the logical operators in my Direichlet condition statements, but I am not sure how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `ContourPlot[potent[x, z], {x, 0, R}, {z, 0, L}]`

Comment: how embarrassing, thanks!